# Upload a file to a specific folder in QC via QTP script

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-quality-center

Duting an automation I get to save the file locally and then i would need to upload it to a specific location in my QC project (in order to retrieve it again later), using a QTP script.

Any ideas on how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google is your friend. For example, the following script from http://h30499.www3.hp.com/t5/Quality-Center-Support-and-News/How-to-upload-a-any-type-of-file-to-quality-center-using-QTP/td-p/5297523#.UfpIs5JM_eQ looks like an answer and is one of the first hits of googling "upload file qc qtp":

```
Dim localFolderPath
localFolderPath = "Local folder path of library files"
call UploadFilesToQC("Subject\BPT RESOURCES\QC Folder Name", localFolderPath )

Public Function UploadFilesToQC(strQCPath,strFilesystemPath)  
    Dim fileCount, timeNow, timeOld, timeDiff
    fileCount = 0
    'Get QC connection object
    Set QCConnection = QCUtil.QCConnection
    'Get Test Plan tree structure
    Set treeManager = QCConnection.TreeManager
    Set node = treeManager.NodeByPath(strQCPath)
    Set AFolder = node.FindChildNode("Library Files")  ' Library Files folder Name in QC
    set oAttachment = AFolder.attachments
    timeOld = Now
    Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    Set oFolder = fso.GetFolder(strFilesystemPath)
    Set oFiles = oFolder.Files
    'Iterate through each file present in File System path
    If oFiles.count >0 Then
    For Each oFile in oFiles
        Set attach = oAttachment.AddItem(Null)
        attach.FileName = oFile.Path
        attach.Type = 1
        attach.Post()
        fileCount = fileCount +1
        Set attach = nothing
    Next
    timeNow = Now
    timeDiff =     timeNow - timeOld
'Time required to upload all files to QC
    Reporter.ReportEvent micDone,"Time required to upload : ", "'" & timeDiff & "' minutes."
'Total Files count uploaded to QC
    Reporter.ReportEvent micDone,"Total files uploaded : ", "'" & fileCount & "' files uploaded."
    else
        Reporter.ReportEvent micFail,"File not found", "No file found at path: " & strFilesystemPath
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: i have not accepted as I have not tried it yet! but i will definetely help so ok ;)

Comment: Yeay, you made it :-)